# Quality factor of an LCR circuit

Tags: electrical-resistance, capacitance, resonance, inductance

The quality factor of an LCR circuit is defined as: $$\omega°/2\delta\omega$$

$\omega°$ stands for the resonant frequency, and $\delta\omega$ for the range of frequencies between half power point and the resonant frequency.

I understand why $\delta\omega$ is in the equation, because lesser the range, better the quality, but why should resonant frequency be there?

For the same $\delta\omega$, a higher or lower $\omega°$ does not increase or decrease the quality, right?

Answer (score 2):

The quality factor is a ration and tells you something about the sharpness of the resonant curve.

If you had a resonance at $\omega^{\prime \prime}= 500$ and $\delta \omega = 5$ and compare it with $\omega^{\prime \prime}= 5000000$ and $\delta \omega = 5$ then which has the sharper resonance?

What about If you had a resonance at $\omega^{\prime \prime}= 500$ and $\delta \omega = 5$ and compare it with $\omega^{\prime \prime}= 5000000$ and $\delta \omega = 50000$ now which has the sharper resonance?